# Color citation using biblatex : in-text + references (issue with postnote + bibliography)

Tags: biblatex, formatting, color

I want to color my citations using biblatex alphabetic citation style. However, I do not to only color the "key" (as it is the case in [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0142694X15000137/1-s2.0-S0142694X15000137-main.pdf?_tid=72252744-23f2-11e5-9f7e-00000aacb360&acdnat=1436196171_cb4985a8a8a15fb814227f92dfd1ea29)) but the whole block including :

- opening bracket (or brace)
- (possible) pre-note : for example '*cf.*'
- the "key" (depending on the citation style - '*Abc90*' in my case)
- (possible) post-note : for example '*p. 1337 sqq*.'
- closing bracket (or brace)

I succeed in colouring the key + the brackets around the citation (+ the colon in case of multiple keys cited).

However, I don't know how to color the postnote ('*p. 43*' in the MWE) and the key in the bibliography ('*Joh73*')

My MWE is :

```
\documentclass{article}

%== inclue bib file ==%
\usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{referencia.bib}
    @misc{john-73,
        author = {John, S.},
        year = {1973},
        title = {The best book ever},
    }
    \end{filecontents}

%== use and define color ==%
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
    \definecolor{bleu_cite}{RGB}{12,127,172}

%== use color in citations ==%
\usepackage[
            colorlinks=true,        
            allcolors = black,  
            citecolor=bleu_cite,        
        ]{hyperref} 

%== biblatex options ==%
\PassOptionsToPackage{
            natbib=true,
            backend=biber,      
            style=alphabetic,       
        }{biblatex}         
        \usepackage{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{referencia.bib}

    \makeatletter 
        \renewcommand*{\bibleftbracket}{\blx@postpunct\textcolor{bleu_cite}{[}}
        \renewcommand*{\bibrightbracket}{\blx@postpunct\textcolor{bleu_cite}{]}\midsentence} 
        \renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\textcolor{bleu_cite}{\addsemicolon\space}}
        \renewcommand*{\citesetup}{\textcolor{bleu_cite}}
    \makeatother


\begin{document}

``Some quotation'' \citep[43]{john-73}.
\printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to colour the citations or do you also want the link to extend to all the parts you listed above

Comment: In case you want colour only, you need just one line: `\AtEveryCite{\color{bleu_cite}}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To colour only specific cite commands it seems easiest to define a new coloured wrapper as replacement for `\mkbibbrackets`

```
\newcommand{\mkbibbracketscol}[1]{\textcolor{bleu_cite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
```

Then, all of the commands using `\mkbibbrackets` we want coloured need to use the new command, while those using nothing just get `\textcolor{bleu_cite}` in their wrapper. The definitions below are copied from the relevant `.cbx` file, in our case `alphabetic.cbx`, and them modified to use `\mkbibbracketscol` or `\textcolor{bleu_cite}` as appropriate.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbracketscol]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibbracketscol]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}[\textcolor{bleu_cite}]
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
  \definecolor{bleu_cite}{RGB}{12,127,172}
\usepackage[
            colorlinks=true,        
            allcolors = black,  
            citecolor=bleu_cite,        
        ]{hyperref} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{
            natbib=true,
            backend=biber,      
            style=alphabetic,       
        }{biblatex}         
        \usepackage{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%\AtEveryCite{\color{bleu_cite}}

\newcommand{\mkbibbracketscol}[1]{\textcolor{bleu_cite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbracketscol]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibbracketscol]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}[\textcolor{bleu_cite}]
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\begin{document}
Lorem \citep[43]{geer} ipsum \citeauthor{worman} dolor \citet[43]{geer} sit \citetitle{worman} amet.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If it is mere colouring for all citation commands you are after and not hyper-linking, you should be happy with

```
\AtEveryCite{\color{bleu_cite}}
```

which will turn the entire citation in a nice *bleu* hue; the link, however, will still be confined to the label.

[image]

Comment: works well... maybe to well, because if I `citeauthor{geer}` or `\citetitle{geer}`, they also appear in blue.

What I would like to do, is to make the link (here _Gee85_) **and** the rest of the tag (here "_[_" as prefix and "_, p.43]_" as suffix) appear in blue.

To make **only** the link appear in blue, as you mentionned `\usepackage[
            colorlinks=true,        
            allcolors = black,  
            citecolor=bleu_cite,        
        ]{hyperref}` works well.
But `\AtEveryCite{\color{bleu_cite}}` works "too much" for what I want to do...

Comment: @ebo Well, that does complicate things quite a bit, see the updated answer, please.

Comment: didn't found `alphabetic.cbx` on my computer. I found [an online version](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/cbx/) of this file, but where should I copy it ?

Comment: @ebo If you have a working `biblatex` installation, you should be able to locate the file via `kpsewhich alphabetic.cbx` (on my system that is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx`). For the answer it is not importand that you find `alphebtic.cbx` you do not need to change any of its contents (and you should not do it either). When I wrote that the definitions need to be copied I was just explaining where I got the base for the code from (and allowing people who might use a different style to find a way to do the same).

Comment: so what I do is just create a file in my `*.tex` files folder called `alphabetic.cbx` with only the parameters I want to change, and this file will overwrite default settings, right ?

Comment: @ebo No, no no. You only need the code in the MWE above in your preamble (the `\newcommand{\mkbibbracketscol}` and the three `\DeclareCiteCommand`s are enough), nothing more and nothing less. If you wish so, you can create an external file called, say `colourcite.tex`, add the modifications of the MWE to this file and call it in your preamble with `\input{colourcite}`.

Comment: @ebo If you were to create a file called `alphabetic.cbx` somewhere that takes precedence over the standard file you will overwrite the default, but the default of `alphabetic.cbx` would not even be loaded and then you would be missing lots of definitions. That is certainly not what you want. Did you run my example from above?

Comment: I had issues indeed, since the other definitions of `alphabetic.cbx` wasn't found.
Your MWE works like a charm, thank you a lot. I'll continue to fiddle it, but it solves my issue !