# Color in-text citation using biblatex - fixing a minor glitch

Tags: biblatex

I wanted all in-text citations in a different color to make them stand out from the text. I used a solution provided by following link.
[Color citation using biblatex : in-text + references (issue with postnote + bibliography)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253927/color-citation-using-biblatex-in-text-references-issue-with-postnote-bibl/386131?noredirect=1#comment956720_386131)
In particular, I used `\AtEveryCite` command. The closing parenthesis is also colored blue. However, the period mark when the references are at the end of a sentence should be black, but above commands makes them blue. Any way to fix this minor glitch? Thanks. Jay

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, %bibtex worked well
style=authoryear-comp, %nature for numbered style
sorting=nyt, % cite according to author's last name,year and title.
maxbibnames=3]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % colouring of raws and also for R code grey background
\definecolor{bleu_cite}{RGB}{34,111,212} % pure blue: {0,0,128}, light blue:{80,135,208}
\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,        
allcolors = black,  
citecolor=bleu_cite,        
]{hyperref} 
\AtEveryCite{\color{bleu_cite}}

\begin{document}
     This is a borrowed fact \parencite{aristotle:physics}. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: The `12 pt`  should probably be `12pt` (no space).

Comment: `\AtEveryCiteKey` is commented in moewe's code and `\mkbibbracketscol` is introduced. The example given by moewe does not have coloured periods. Please test his example to confirm.

Comment: Thanks Johannes :) Yes, his command works, as in the periods are in black. However, some references disappear and there is extra spaces between references - both are risky when revising a thesis. Therefore, I won't be chasing this option further, but it could work with tweaking.

Comment: You would need to show the extra spaces in the example to get help.

Comment: If you found a problem with my solution I would be grateful for an example that shows the problem. Note that you use a vastly different style to the one in the other question, so you can't just copy the `\DeclareCiteCommand` you will have to adapt those in `authoryear-comp`.

Comment: `autopunct=false` might be enough for `AtEveryCite{\color{bleu_cite}}`, but then you turn off that feature entirely.

Answer (score 3):

By default `biblatex` scans ahead for punctuation after a citation to avoid double punctuation. This means that `biblatex` 'takes over' printing punctuation directly after the citation. You can turn off this feature with

```
autopunct=false
```

Then you can continue to use `\AtEveryCite{\color{bleu_cite}}`.

---

But you can also use the `\DeclareCiteCommand` approach from [Color citation using biblatex : in-text + references (issue with postnote + bibliography)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253927/35864). You will have to modify this for your style, though.

```
\newcommand{\mkbibparenscol}[1]{\textcolor{bleu_cite}{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\textcolor{bleu_cite}]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparenscol]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```