# Custom citation (coloured) for select keys only

Tags: biblatex, color, citing

Is there any way, using biblatex, to get citations for certain bib-keys / bib-entries, and only them, to be differently coloured?

In the MWE below, I've made a custom command (inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258415/14884)) for differently coloured citations. However, what I am looking for is a way of having biblatex/biber *automatically colour citations referencing certain entries, and only them*, without using any custom commands. In the text, the same command would be used (e.g. `\parencite`) but for specified entries (e.g. `articlecoloured`) the output would be coloured; for other entries, it would not.

In other words, using the citation commands as in section "No custom commands" in the MWE but getting the same output as in section "Using custom commands".

[image]

The example includes a bib-content with two entries, `articlenormal` and `articlecoloured`.

I'd like to be able to use the normal citation commands (`\parencite`, `\citeyear`, `\textcite` etc.) but for some bib-keys (`articlecoloured`) output would be coloured; for all others (e.g. `articlenormal`) it would not. (In my working document, I have custom commands for the various citation commands I use, which all colour output as in the MWE. In the MWE, I've only included `\parencite`.)

Is it possible to get `articlecoloured`, and only `articlecoloured`, to have a custom colour *without using a custom citation command?*

Perhaps which bibentries to colour could be based either on a list of keys (i.e. `articlecoloured`), or to have a relevant keyword in the bibentry?

(Bonus points if specified entry to be coloured is also coloured in the bibliography.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{citecolor}{RGB}{12,127,172}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@ARTICLE{articlenormal,
    author = {Normal, Article},
    title = {Normal},
    year = {2020}
}
@ARTICLE{articlecoloured,
    author = {Coloured, Article},
    title = {Coloured},
    year = {2020}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{british-apa}

\bibliography{mybib}

% Using custom command
\newcommand{\mkbibparenscoloured}[1]{\textcolor{citecolor}{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{finalnamedelim}
  {\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\colparencite}[\mkbibparenscoloured]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}%
   \toggletrue{apa:inpcite}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \togglefalse{apa:inpcite}}

\begin{document}

\section*{No custom commands}

Citation, should be normal colour \parencite{articlenormal}.

Citation, should be differently coloured \parencite{articlecoloured}.

\section*{Using custom commands}

Citation, should be normal colour \parencite{articlenormal}.

Citation, should be differently coloured \colparencite{articlecoloured}.

\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it OK if the parentheses around the citation are not coloured? That would make things a *lot* easier for cases like `\parencite{articlenormal,articlecoloured}`.

Comment: @moewe Yes! Not only would it be OK but even preferred, given that I _would_ have cases such as the one in your example (mixing non-coloured references with coloured in citations)! Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Phew! Still `\textcite` is going to be tricky, I'll see what can be done. (Of course `biblatex-apa` is quite a complex style, so things are going to be more tricky than with your average `authoryear`. Can you please check the version of `biblatex-apa` that you have installed? You can add `\listfiles` to the beginning of your file and then read off the version in the `.log` file output.)

Comment: `biblatex.def    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)`
`standard.bbx    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)`
`apa.bbx    2017/01/06 v7.4 APA biblatex references style`

Hmm. That `apa.bbx` looks old. I think it's an old remnant in my local-texmf. I'll remove that and re-run with texmf-dist biblatex-apa.

Comment: Mhhh, why is your `biblatex-apa` so old, but your `biblatex` is current? Note that your version of `biblatex-apa` produces the (now outdated) 6th-edition APA style. A current versions of `biblatex-apa` (v9.6) will produce 7th-edition APA style. If you want 6th-edition APA style on an up-to-date system, you would be using `biblatex-apa6`'s `style=apa6,`.

Comment: Yes. Not sure why I (seemingly three years ago) added `biblatex-apa` to texmf-local. Removed that and now have a current biblatex-apa: `apa.bbx    2019/11/29 v9.2 APA biblatex references style`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry to be a pain, but just to be clear: Is 7th-edition APA style what you want (in which case `style=apa,` is the correct choice) or do you want 6th-edition APA style (in which case you'll want `style=apa6,`)?

Comment: You're not being a pain but helpful! To be honest, I could choose whichever, but let's stick with `style=apa` so APA7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially we 'just' need to take the original definition of the `cite` and `textcite` bibmacros and sprinkle some colour in there.

The original definitions can be found in `apa.cbx` ([ll. 189-261 in v9.6](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/b9ed20f69894145aa32c6781f2fe6530b50784e7/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/cbx/apa.cbx#L189-L261)).

In this example you can define which citations are going to be coloured with

```
\addtocategory{coloured}{<key_1,key_2,...,key_n>}
```

so this is useful if the entry is only coloured in the context of a certain document and not in and of itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citecolour}{RGB}{12,127,172}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{coloured}
\addtocategory{coloured}{articlecoloured}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citecolour:conditional}{%
  \ifcategory{coloured}
    {\textcolor{citecolour}{#1}}
    {#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
   {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
    \printtext[citecolour:conditional]{%
      \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}}%
   {\printtext[citecolour:conditional]{%
      \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
         \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}%
         \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
       {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
         {\printnames{labelname}}%
         {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
           {\printnames{shortauthor}}
           {\ifnameundef{groupauthor}
             {\printnames[labelname]{author}}
             {\printnames[labelname]{groupauthor}}%
            \addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
         \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}%
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}%
   \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
     \printtext[citecolour:conditional]{%
       \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}}
    {%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
      \setunit{\compcitedelim}%
      \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
         {\printtext[citecolour:conditional]{%
            \usebibmacro{cite:noname}}%
          \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:np}%
                   {\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
                   {\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
          \printtext[citecolour:conditional]{%
            \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}}
         {\printtext[citecolour:conditional]{%
            \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
       {\printtext[citecolour:conditional]{%
          \ifnameundef{shortauthor}%
           {\printnames{labelname}}
           {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
             {\printnames{shortauthor}}
             {\ifnameundef{groupauthor}
               {\printnames[labelname]{author}}
               {\printnames[labelname]{groupauthor}}}}}%
        \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:np}
                  {\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}
                  {\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
        \printtext[citecolour:conditional]{%
          \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
           {}
           {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
             {}
             {\printnames{shortauthor}\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}%
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
    {\ifcategory{coloured}
       {\color{citecolour}}
       {}%
      \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:in}%
      \global\let\blx@related@loop\@empty}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitebib}
  {\list{}
   {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
     \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}\item}
  {\usedriver
    {\ifcategory{coloured}
       {\color{citecolour}}
       {}%
      \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
      \global\boolfalse{bbx:in}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}%
   \finentry
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {\item}
  {\endlist}
\makeatother

% for the bibliography
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifcategory{coloured}
    {\color{citecolour}}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{articlenormal,
    author = {Normal, Article},
    title  = {Normal},
    year   = {2020},
}
@article{articlecoloured,
    author = {Coloured, Article},
    title  = {Coloured},
    year   = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Citation, should be normal colour \parencite{articlenormal}.

Citation, should be differently coloured \parencite{articlecoloured}.

Citation, should be normal colour \textcite{articlenormal}.

Citation, should be differently coloured \textcite{articlecoloured}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Coloured citations.]

---

If the entry is coloured by its very nature, it would be more natural to work with `keyowrds`

Simply replace the

```
\ifcategory{coloured}
```

above with

```
\ifkeyword{coloured}
```

and mark coloured entries up with

```
keywords = {coloured},
```

in the `.bib` file.

Comment:  Brilliant! Many thanks for taking the time. Much, much appreciated!

I've been trying to use your code to implement colouring for `\fullcite` as well, but as far as I can tell it seems to follow a different kind of logic. I'll see if I can get it working myself and if not, perhaps I'll resort to a `\colourfullcite`, as there are only a handful instances of `\fullcite` in the document.

Seeing all the correct references being coloured throughout the whole thesis was a joy! Thank you again.

Comment: @krissen Ah yes, `\fullcite` is not implemented via a dedicated bibmacro, it is declared directly with `\DeclareCiteCommand`. Somehow the straightforward solution there seems to create an unwanted space, I'll have to investigate (but probably only tomorrow).

Comment: @krissen I added the required code for a coloured `\fullcite`. You may see an undesirable space in sparsely populated entries (such as the ones in the MWE), see https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/97 for details. Hopefully this is going to be fixed soon.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. In my actual document, the bib-entries are more populated so the undesirerable space is not an issue. 

At first, I only inserted the fullcite-code in my document, which led to odd output. Then, I inserted the full code, and ended up with no colour. Still, happy to have been able to figure out by myself, that in the current code you posted you used the _keyword_ -approach, not category. Reverting relevant code from `keyword` to `category` and everything works as expected. Thank you again for taking the time! Much, much appreciated!

Comment: @krissen Oh yeah, sorry about the copy-and-paste screw-up. Should hopefully be fixed now.